# Files are not dowloading when file names with special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Files are not downloading and doesn't show any information
 which is present in the file. Some time it shows one messages,i.e.,file is corrupted or unknown file type.

```
injurydocObj=[self.injuryDocSN objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *path = injurydocObj.athleteDoumentPath;
NSString *fileName=injurydocObj.documentName;

path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\"
                                     withString:@"/"];
path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSString *strFileType=@"";
NSArray *arFileName = [fileName componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if(arFileName.count>0)
{
    strFileType = arFileName[arFileName.count-1];
    strFileType = [strFileType lowercaseString];
}
if([strFileType isEqual:@"doc"] || [strFileType isEqual:@"docx"] || [strFileType isEqual:@"pdf"]){

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];

}`
```

Please help me to display pdf, doc and docx files types even file name includes special characters or spaces

Comment: Use the URL related API rather than messing up the paths with `stringByReplacingOccurrences`.

Comment: sorry,I'm not able understanding what you are telling.I'm new to IOS.
My code working fine for file names which are not consist of special characters.
The main problem is with the special characters only.

Comment: Please add an example of a non-working `athleteDoumentPath`.

Comment: EXAMPLE.   :    _athleteDoumentPath  
  @"http://qa.example.com/ExampleDocuments\\Documents\\AthleteID\\RM testing%.doc" .








and 
Document name is   
"RM testing%.doc".

Comment: A valid URL requires to start with a scheme e.g. `http://`. Where does the scheme come from? The example doesn't start with a scheme and in the code none is added.

Comment: above mentioned URL is in correct format only. "http://" is not displaying after post the comment.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the percent encoding with the dedicated API [`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-stringbyaddingpercentencodingwit?language=objc)

```
NSString *path = injurydocObj.athleteDoumentPath;
NSString *fileName = injurydocObj.documentName;
path = [[path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"/"]
        stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: path];

if ([@[@"doc", @"docx", @"pdf"] containsObject: url.pathExtension]) {

...

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
```

Comment: it's not working and even normal files(file names without special characters) also not downloading.error is getting whenever download the file.i.e, "NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100"